# GLPaint Brush Effects

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, ios5, xcode4.2

I am working on a drawing iPhone app based on GLPaint. I want to get the brush effect as you see in the image1. But i could only get a effect similar to image2. The effect i want is to get a line along with the brush when drawn on white background. [image: Screen shots]

Thank you in advance.

Nothing much differ from GLPaint code; Here I have given the glBlendFunc() method that i think should change.

```
 if ((self = [super initWithCoder:coder])) {

CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;

eaglLayer.opaque = YES;

// In this application, we want to retain the EAGLDrawable contents after a call to presentRenderbuffer.

eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking, kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];

context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];

if (!context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context]) {

[self release];

return nil;

}

// Create a texture from an image

// First create a UIImage object from the data in a image file, and then extract the Core Graphics image

brushImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"criclewww.png"].CGImage;

// Get the width and height of the image

width = CGImageGetWidth(brushImage);

height = CGImageGetHeight(brushImage);

// Texture dimensions must be a power of 2. If you write an application that allows users to supply an image,

// you'll want to add code that checks the dimensions and takes appropriate action if they are not a power of 2.

// Make sure the image exists

if(brushImage) {

// Allocate  memory needed for the bitmap context

brushData = (GLubyte *) calloc(width * height * 4, sizeof(GLubyte));

// Use  the bitmatp creation function provided by the Core Graphics framework. 

brushContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(brushData, width, height, 8, width * 4, CGImageGetColorSpace(brushImage), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

// After you create the context, you can draw the  image to the context.

CGContextDrawImage(brushContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (CGFloat)width, (CGFloat)height), brushImage);

// You don't need the context at this point, so you need to release it to avoid memory leaks.

CGContextRelease(brushContext);

// Use OpenGL ES to generate a name for the texture.

glGenTextures(1, &brushTexture);

// Bind the texture name. 

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, brushTexture);

// Set the texture parameters to use a minifying filter and a linear filer (weighted average)

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

// Specify a 2D texture image, providing the a pointer to the image data in memory

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, brushData);

// Release  the image data; it's no longer needed

            free(brushData);

}

// Set the view's scale factor

self.contentScaleFactor = 1.0;



// Setup OpenGL states

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

CGRect frame = self.bounds;

CGFloat scale = self.contentScaleFactor;

// Setup the view port in Pixels

glOrthof(0, frame.size.width * scale, 0, frame.size.height * scale, -1, 1);

glViewport(0, 0, frame.size.width * scale, frame.size.height * scale);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glDisable(GL_DITHER);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

// Set a blending function appropriate for premultiplied alpha pixel data

        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        //(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES);

glTexEnvf(GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES, GL_COORD_REPLACE_OES, GL_TRUE);

glPointSize(width / kBrushScale);

// Make sure to start with a cleared buffer

needsErase = YES;

// Playback recorded path, which is "Shake Me"

recordedPaths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Recording" ofType:@"data"]];

if([recordedPaths count])

[self performSelector:@selector(playback:) withObject:recordedPaths afterDelay:0.2];

}

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

return self;
```

Comment: You should go off and read through the code you have and learn HOW it works, what the functions it calls are doing and how that can affect what you are trying to do. You shouldn't rely on copying and pasting code. We don't know what the drawing code you have does and how it uses the numbers you've put in your question (mostly because you haven't posted your code).

Comment: @NickBull: The code is very much similar to the Apple GLPaint application..Don't misunderstand that I am searching for a code to copy and paste.

Comment: I made that comment to help you - you have taken the GLPaint code, but you need to take the time to learn how it works and what it does. Study the code you have and work out what is happening. What all the functions do - read the docs on the methods that are called.

Comment: I have done paint application. Please post your code. maybe I can help you.

Comment: I'll look in this code and get back to you when I'll get time.